# Why my login function let users login with a random password?

Tags: c#, authentication, bcrypt, login-script

i have a little problem. My Script lets users login with a random password. How can i fix it? Here are all informations: Passworts are stored in MySQL DB V8, and they crypted correctly with BCrypt.

Bcrypt Code:

```
    private static string GetRandomSalt()
{
    return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(10);
}

public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password, GetRandomSalt());
}

public static bool ValidatePassword(string username, string password)
{
    return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(username, password);
}
```

This is my code where i got the problem:

```
[RemoteEvent("loginUser")]
public void loginUserEvent(Client player, String username, String password)
{

    if (player.HasData("waitLogando"))
    {
        player.SendNotification("Wait...");
        return;
    }
    player.SetData("waitLogando", true);
    using (MySqlConnection Mainpipeline = new MySqlConnection(Main.myConnectionString))
    {
        Mainpipeline.Open();
        MySqlCommand query = Mainpipeline.CreateCommand();
        query.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ( `Username` = '" + username + "' OR `email` = '" + username + "')";
        query.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query))
        {

            da.Fill(dt);

            int i = 0;
            i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
            if (i == 0)
            {
                string query2 = "SELECT * FROM users (username, password) VALUES (@username, @password)";

                MySqlCommand LoginAccount = new MySqlCommand(query2, Mainpipeline);

                LoginAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "" + username + "");
                LoginAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", "" + AccountManage.ValidatePassword(username, password) + "");
                LoginAccount.ExecuteNonQuery();

                player.SendNotification("Wrong password");
                player.ResetData("waitLogando");
            }
            else
            {
                NAPI.ClientEvent.TriggerClientEvent(player, "clearLoginWindow");
                AccountManage.LoadAccount(player, username);
                player.ResetData("waitLogando");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really hope you can help me, thanks for your time! If you need more informations, im here.

Comment: Did you step through your program with a debugger? I think you'll find the problem quite quickly.

Comment: Why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` on `query` which is clearly a query?  And I think you meant for `query2` to be an INSERT and not a SELECT.  Finally you never actually compare the password with the hash  in the DB.

Comment: Additionally to what the others have said. Even if you meant that query2 should be an INSERT instead of a SELECT. You are not inserting the hashed password, but AccountManage.ValidatePassword which is either `false` or `true`, which is also very likely not what you intended. Again, use the debugger which will tell you what goes wrong.

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, you should build `query` using parameters like `query2`, rather than string concatenation.

Comment: If i do this i get these error: BCrypt.Net.SaltParseException: Invalid salt version

Comment: Also, your implementation of `ValidatePassword` appears to be wrong. You're passing in the username and the plain text password to BCrypt.Net. According to BCrypt.Net you need to pass it the plain text password as well as the hashed password you stored in the database. See the implementation and comments on `Verify`:https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net/blob/master/src/BCrypt.Net/BCrypt.cs

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the password in the first query, you only check user name or email.

Ah, query2 is also incorrect (did you mean INSERT instead of SELECT?).

Comment: No i mean select, to get the username and password from database, this should only a login function. Register works perfectly. Is there a way to do it smarter? If i check password on first query, the console where i run the dll said me :
BCrypt.Net.SaltParseException: Invalid salt version